# Concatenation of two vectors - why are lengths not treated as commutative?

Tags: idris

I'm playing around with Idris and I came across something which confuses me a little:

The following type checks:

```
conc : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n+m) a
conc [] ys = ys
conc (x :: xs) ys = x :: (conc xs ys)
```

but this doesn't:

```
conc : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (m+n) a
conc [] ys = ys
conc (x :: xs) ys = x :: (conc xs ys)
```

with the following error:

```
When checking right hand side of conc with expected type
        Vect (m + 0) a

Type mismatch between
        Vect m a (Type of ys)
and
        Vect (plus m 0) a (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                m
        and
                plus m 0
```

Equivalently xs++ys type checks but ys++xs doesn't even though they would both match the type definition of having length n+m.

This surprises me a little as addition is commutative. Is there anything I can do (perhaps with constraints?) to the function signature to get both xs++ys and ys++xs expressions type checking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common topic of confusion for beginners in *Idris*.
The problem in this case in second `conc` version:

```
conc : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (m+n) a
conc [] ys = ys
```

*Idris* cannot apply addition commutativity because *Nat plus commutativity* is a theorem from the compiler point of view. Here its type:

```
Idris> :t plusCommutative 
plusCommutative : (left : Nat) -> (right : Nat) -> left + right = right + left
```

There're no general rules to tell you which theorem to choose and to apply. Of course, some heuristics can be made for some simple cases, like *Nat commutativity*. But this also can make difficult to understand some other cases.

The other thing you need to consider is definition of `plus`:

```
Idris> :printdef plus 
plus : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
plus 0 right = right
plus (S left) right = S (plus left right)
```

Function `plus` defined in a such way that is does pattern matching on its first argument. *Idris* actually can perform this pattern matching in types. So in first version, where

```
conc : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n+m) a
conc [] ys = ys
```

you have (0 + m) in type and *Idris* can replace `plus 0 m` with `m` and everything typechecks. `plus m 0` would work if you define your `+` operator by pattern matching on second argument. For example, this compiles:

```
infixl 4 +.
(+.) : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
n +. Z = n
n +. (S m) = S (n +. m)

conc : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (m +. n) a
conc [] ys = ys
conc (x :: xs) ys = x :: (conc xs ys)
```

But it's obvious that writing new operator for every case you need is horrible. So to make your second version compilable you should use `rewrite ... in` syntax in *Idris*. You need next theorems:

```
Idris> :t plusZeroRightNeutral 
plusZeroRightNeutral : (left : Nat) -> left + 0 = left
Idris> :t plusSuccRightSucc 
plusSuccRightSucc : (left : Nat) -> (right : Nat) -> S (left + right) = left + S right
Idris> :t sym
sym : (left = right) -> right = left
```

And here is version which compiles:

```
conc : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (m + n) a
conc         {m} []        ys = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral m        in ys
conc {n=S k} {m} (x :: xs) ys = rewrite (sym $ plusSuccRightSucc m k) in x :: (conc xs ys)
```

I'm not explaining here how `rewriting` and theorem proving works here. This is a topic of another question if you don't understand something. But you can read about that in tutorial (or wait for The Book release :) .

Comment: Great stuff - that's really clear. I'm actually just starting working through 'The Book' at the moment, I bought the MEAP when it came out but hadn't made time to go through it until now.