# How exactly does rewrite work in Idris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I wrote the following proposition in Idris:

```
total
plusOneCommutes : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> (n + S m = S n + m)
plusOneCommutes Z     k     = Refl
plusOneCommutes (S k) j     = 
 let inductiveHypothesis = plusOneCommutes k j in
   rewrite inductiveHypothesis in Refl
```

Using inspiration from the `Prelude.Nat` source code, I understand why it makes sense to use the recursive call (in the second case) as an induction hypothesis in order to prove the case. However, going through the details of the rewriting with holes, I don't really grok what's going on and why this works.

If I write:

```
plusOneCommutes (S k) j     = ?hole
```

I get the following from the compiler:

```
- + HolyGrail.hole [P]
 `--               k : Nat
                   j : Nat
     ------------------------------------------------------
      HolyGrail.hole : S (plus k (S j)) = S (S (plus k j))
```

which does not really seem right. According to the signature of `plusOneCommutes` this hole should have type `(plus (S k) (S j)) = (plus (S (S k)) j)`.

Going one step further and introducing induction hypothesis, if I write:

```
plusOneCommutes (S k) j     = 
 let inductiveHypothesis = plusOneCommutes k j in
   ?hole
```

then type of `hole` becomes:

```
 - + HolyGrail.hole [P]
  `--                    k : Nat
                         j : Nat
       inductiveHypothesis : k + S j = S k + j
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
       HolyGrail.hole : S (plus k (S j))  = S (S (plus k j))
```

then using the rewrite rule given by `inductiveHypothesis`

```
 - + HolyGrail.hole [P]
  `--                    k : Nat
                         j : Nat
       inductiveHypothesis : k + S j = S k + j
             _rewrite_rule : k + S j = S k + j
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
       HolyGrail.hole : (\replaced => S replaced = S (S (plus k j))) (S k + j)
```

which leads to `S (plus (S k) j) = S (S (plus k j))` which is the expected type, and Idris can complete the proof automatically replacing `?hole` with `Refl`.

What's puzzling me then is the unexpected difference in types between what I infer from the signature and what the compiler infers from the hole. If I introduce voluntarily an error:

I get the following message:

```
 - + Errors (1)
  `-- HolyGrail.idr line 121 col 16:
      When checking right hand side of plusOneCommutes with expected type
              S k + S j = S (S k) + j

      Type mismatch between
              S (S (plus k j)) = S (S (plus k j)) (Type of Refl)
      and
              S (plus k (S j)) = S (S (plus k j)) (Expected type)

      Specifically:
              Type mismatch between
                      S (plus k j)
              and
                      plus k (S j)
```

The `Type mismatch...` part is consistent with the above steps but not the `When checking ...` part which gives the type I would expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following from compiler actually makes sense:

```
- + HolyGrail.hole [P]
 `--               k : Nat
                   j : Nat
     ------------------------------------------------------
      HolyGrail.hole : S (plus k (S j)) = S (S (plus k j))
```

In the left side of `=` in type you have `n + S m`. After pattern matching on `n` you have `(S k)` and should have `S k + S j` in type which is `plus (S k) (S j)`. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534191/concatenation-of-two-vectors-why-are-lengths-not-treated-as-commutative) I explained one important point: from the fact how `plus` function is written and fact that compiler can perform pattern matching in types you're seeing `S (plus k (S j))` which is just applying `plus` to `(S k)` and `(S j)`. Similar situation with `S n + m`.

Now to `rewrite`. In *Agda* programming language `rewrite` is just syntax sugar for pattern matching on `Refl`. And sometimes you can replace `rewrite` with pattern matching in *Idris* but not in this case.

We can try to do something similar. Consider next:

```
total
plusOneCommutes : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> (n + S m = S n + m)
plusOneCommutes Z     k     = Refl
plusOneCommutes (S k) j     = case plusOneCommutes k j of
    prf => ?hole
```

Compiler says next very reasonable things:

```
- + HolyGrail.hole [P]
 `--               k : Nat
                   j : Nat
                 prf : k + S j = S k + j
     ------------------------------------------------------
      HolyGrail.hole : S (plus k (S j)) = S (S (plus k j))
```

`prf` is something that proves `k + S j = S k + j` which makes sense. And after using `rewrite`:

```
plusOneCommutes (S k) j     = case plusOneCommutes k j of
    prf => rewrite prf in ?hole
```

We got:

```
- + HolyGrail.hole [P]
 `--               k : Nat
                   j : Nat
                 prf : k + S j = S k + j
       _rewrite_rule : k + S j = S k + j
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      HolyGrail.hole : (\replaced => S replaced = S (S (plus k j))) (S k + j)
```

`rewrite` in *Idris* behaves in the following way:

1. Takes `Refl : left = right` object and `expr : t`.
2. Searches `left` in `t`.
3. Replaces all occurrences of `left` with `right` in `t`.

In our case:

1. `t` is `S (plus k (S j)) = S (S (plus k j))`
2. `Refl : plus k (S j) = plus (S k) j`

   - `left` is `plus k (S j)`
   - `right` is `plus (S k) j`
3. Idris replaces `plus k (S j)` (left) with `plus (S k) j` (right) in `t` and we get `S (plus (S k) j) = S (S (plus k j))`. Idris can perform pattern matching which it does. And `S (plus (S k) j)` naturally becomes `S (S (plus k j))`.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the part about the definition of plus! Everything makes sense then :)

Comment: "rewrite in Idris takes object of type Refl, searches left side of = in the expression after in and replaces it with the right side of = of given Refl"

Isn't it the other way around? `myPlusCommutes Z m = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral m in Refl` --  here we need a `m = plus m 0`, so right **right side** of `m = m` (`Refl : x=x` after `in`) is replaced with the **left side** of `plusZeroRightNeutral m : m + 0 = m`

Comment: Also, Relf is not a type, it's a term.

Comment: @corazza Not sure about the other way around. In my example I have a proof `plus k (S j) = plus (S k) j`. I want to prove `S (plus k (S j)) = S (S (plus k j))`. After `rewrite` Idris replaces `plus k (S j)` (left side of proof I have) in `S (plus k (S j))` (left side of proof I want) with `plus (S k) j` (right side of proof I have). You can see lambda in last code snippet.

Comment: @corazza I've actually meant the right thing. But I've described it in a wrong way. Now explanation is more formal and precise.

Comment: @dader This was fixed as well.