# Additional pattern matching on the second argument in `plus` for `Nat` type

Tags: pattern-matching, proof, idris, dependent-type

I found out that `plus` function for `Nat`s is implemented in [this way](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/9fc97f9b4ec2a75bc576c52994299037a606cc74/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L64-L66)

```
total plus : (n, m : Nat) -> Nat
plus Z right        = right
plus (S left) right = S (plus left right)
```

I wonder if there is particular reason not to pattern match on the second argument as well like here:

```
total plus : (n, m : Nat) -> Nat
plus Z right        = right
plus left Z         = left
plus (S left) right = S (plus left right)
```

As I see for the moment this implementation would make life simpler in many proofs and code. For example

```
total plusZeroRightNeutral : (left : Nat) -> left + 0 = left
plusZeroRightNeutral Z     = Refl
plusZeroRightNeutral (S n) =
  let inductiveHypothesis = plusZeroRightNeutral n in
    rewrite inductiveHypothesis in Refl
```

would look like `plusZeroLeftNeutral` :

```
total plusZeroRightNeutral : (left : Nat) -> left + 0 = left
plusZeroRightNeutral left = Refl
```

In real life we don't even need to use `plusZeroLeftNeutral` theorem because Idris can do pattern matching automatically (as it already mentioned in the answer to this question: [Concatenation of two vectors - why are lengths not treated as commutative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534191/concatenation-of-two-vectors-why-are-lengths-not-treated-as-commutative) ).

So why not add extra cases to make life easier?

Comment: Have you tried proving the new `plusZeroLeftNeutral` lemma as you suggest?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Hmm, it doesn't work, but it doesn't make any sense to me. I would love to see explanation even if that is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `plusZeroLeftNeutral` cannot be proved with just `Refl`.

When you use `Refl` you are saying: "this holds by computation" (another name for this is definitional equality, or judgemental equality).

But how do we compute `left + 0` (i.e. `plus left Z` for the `Nat` type)? Essentially, Idris processes function definitions clause by clause from top to bottom, and in our case it first looks at `plus Z right` clause. At this point Idris needs to decide if `left` is `Z`, but it cannot, because we have not destructed `left`. Idris cannot skip the first clause and go to `plus left Z` clause.

Now, with this alternative definition for `plus` one does not need induction for the proof of right neutrality of addition:

```
total plusZeroRightNeutral : (left : Nat) -> plus left 0 = left
plusZeroRightNeutral Z = Refl
plusZeroRightNeutral (S _) = Refl
```

But on the other hand, many proofs become long-winded because they now need more pattern-matching. Let's take the associativity of addition. Here is a possible proof for this fact for the original definition of `plus`:

```
total plusAssoc : (m,n,p : Nat) -> m + (n + p) = m + n + p
plusAssoc Z n p = Refl
plusAssoc (S m) n p = cong $ plusAssoc m n p
```

And here as the corresponding proof for the modified `plus`:

```
total plusAssoc : (m,n,p : Nat) -> m + (n + p) = m + n + p
plusAssoc Z n p = Refl
plusAssoc (S m) Z p = Refl
plusAssoc (S m) (S n) Z = Refl
plusAssoc (S m) (S n) (S p) = cong $ plusAssoc m (S n) (S p)
```

Here you are forced to destruct the second arguments of the occurrences of `plus` function simply because those block evaluation, but you need to move `S` constructors out of the way to be able to utilize your induction hypothesis.

Comment: Conor McBride explains this thing in his CS410 (2017) course, see [Lecture 3 (Proof by Induction), around 21:33](https://youtu.be/8xFT9FPlm18?t=1293).